# MVC4 Linq Database Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Working on my first `MVC` app.  I am using the simple membership database that comes with MVC4 to manage users and roles.  My understanding is that I am having to do three steps for the `Find()` call below to work: get the simple membership `GUID` of the person logged in, use the simple membership `GUID` to get the ID in my Couriers database, then use that ID as the missing parameter in the `Find()` call below to return the model / record to edit in the view?  
How / what do I use as the parameter to the .Find() call?  Am I on the right track, or making this a lot more complicated?

ps - I am saving the membership `GUID` in the Couriers database in a separate column from the Courier ID primary key column when the Courier record is created.  Thank you.

```
   public ActionResult EditCourier()
    {
        System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        var providerUserKey = user.ProviderUserKey;
        Guid userId = (Guid)providerUserKey;
        String userIDstring = userId.ToString();

        var model =
            from c in db.Couriers
            where c.CourierMembershipID == userIDstring
            select c.ID;

        Courier courier = db.Couriers.Find();

        if (courier == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(courier);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN documentation says:

> Uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the
>   context. If the entity is not in the context then a query will be
>   executed and evaluated against the data in the data source, and null
>   is returned if the entity is not found in the context or in the data
>   source.

So if you have userId as a primary key in Couriers table then you can use [.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) like this:

```
Courier courier = db.Couriers.Find(userId);
```

Otherwise you should use standard LINQ query and then call `.FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` method:

```
Courier courier = db.Couriers.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CourierMembershipID == userIDstring);
```

EDIT:

I suppose you getting this error from next query:

```
var model =
            from c in db.Couriers
            where c.CourierMembershipID == userIDstring
            select c.ID;
```

The reason is that you getting from this query `IEnumerable<Courier>` model.
For making this query to get single `Courier` object try to call `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end:

```
var model =    (from c in db.Couriers
                where c.CourierMembershipID == userIDstring
                select c.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have simplified my problem a little bit.  So, please let me ask it this way.  I am trying to return a single record with the linq query back to the view but I am getting the cannot convert ienumberable to Courier error message

Comment: Thank you very much.  Using .First was a huge help in moving forward with this issue.  I'll try the FirstOrDefault as well.